# How can I add a column of zeros to the right side of a table in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a table with one column filled with 8 trial types, e.g.:

- nochangetrial
- changeordertrial
- changepitchtrial
- etc.

I need to add a column to the right in which to put accuracy rates for the trial types. But after a few hours, I cannot find it. Matlab docs explain a lot about tables but not how to add a new column, and not how to add a column filled with a number (e.g., zeroes).

Answer (score 0):

If we consider that your table is `A`, and the column you want to add on the right is `b`, then try this:

```
A= [A b];
```

The number of rows of `A` and `b` must agree.

Comment: That's for a **matrix**, not a table.

Comment: its the same men -_- , check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-and-delete-table-variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say T1 is your table with the trial types.
If you make a second table T2 with the accuracies, then you can concatenate the two:

```
T1 = table(TrialType);
T2 = table(Accuracy);
T = [T1 T2];
```

Here TrialType and Accuracy are just a cell array and a matrix.